# escaping javascript for a loop in rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, escaping

When I try to do the following in a .js.erb file:

```
$("#id").html( "<%= escape_javascript( 

    @units.each do |unit|                   
      sync partial: 'edit_unit', resource: unit 
    end

)  %>" );
```

I get an error:

```
undefined method `gsub' for #<Array:0x6e2cc98>
```

I've tested the rails code separately (i.e. in a rails view, as opposed to .js.erb file) and it appears to word fine.

Am I using the html() and escape_javascript() methods correctly?

Note: I'm using the 'sync' gem, hence the sync partial call.

Comment: The error you describe is not being raised from the snippet you provided.

Comment: Not sure what you mean? That's the error I get. i.e. Showing C:/Sites/scoot/app/views/units/show_DU_change.js.erb where line #47 raised:
undefined method `gsub' for #<Array:0x5461020>

Comment: I've checked that @units is being loaded correctly, that the ruby code works in an html.erb file.